# Real orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be an orthogonal matrix $(AA^t=I)$ and $a+ib$ an eigenvector $$A\cdot (a+ib)=\lambda \cdot (a+ib)$$ where $\lambda \in \mathbb{C} -\mathbb{R}$.

How to prove that $$ ||a||=||b||$$ $$ \langle a,b\rangle=0$$
$a+ib\in \mathbb{C}^n$

$a+ib=(a_1+ib_1,a_2+ib_2,\cdots,a_n+ib_n)$

$a=(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n$

$b=(b_1,b_2,\cdots,b_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n$

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** As $A$ is a real matrix and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, so is $\overline{\lambda}$ (the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is a real polynomial so complex roots occur in conjugate pairs). You should be able to determine an eigenvector for $\overline{\lambda}$ in terms of the eigenvector for $\lambda$ (this is actually easier than it sounds). Finally, use the fact that eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are orthogonal.